# how to convert json string in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have string response like this, I got only below response of my api.

```
{authToken: msadnmsandnasdn}
```

and I have to convert as below.

```
{"authToken": "msadnmsandnasdn"}
```

So how i can do this please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various manipulation operations to do that manually:

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  var s = "{authToken: msadnmsandnasdn, name:risheek}";
  
  var kv = s.substring(0,s.length-1).substring(1).split(",");
  final Map<String, String> pairs = {};
  
  for (int i=0; i < kv.length;i++){
    var thisKV = kv[i].split(":");
    pairs[thisKV[0]] =thisKV[1].trim();
  }
  
  var encoded = json.encode(pairs);
  print(encoded);
}
```

Output:

```
{"authToken":"msadnmsandnasdn"," name":"risheek"}
```

Comment: msadnmsandnasdn.... means i got only token nothing else, i can edit the question.

Comment: yeah yeah just insert your string as `var s` and use it however you want it'll work the same

Comment: can you upvote as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jsonDecode on that string like this:

```
var response = {authToken: msadnmsandnasdn....};
var result = jsonDecode(response);
```

Comment: i tried you code but it returns "Uncaught Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1
"